# trigger after insertion method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to built trigger in which when user delete a row after deleted user will able to view the row which he deleted.

i have tried my coading is follows
please help.

```
create trigger insertion
before insert on client
for each row
as
select * from client
```

Comment: Help with what? Is something not working? What is your question?

Comment: sorry for bad english sir.

Comment: sir i want that when i delete a row from table after the row deleted it automatically select the deleted row and show the row which i have deleted.

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: Selects and shows it where? In SSMS?

Comment: Please think: You should already know what you are deleting. So why do you need a trigger.?

Comment: when we delete a row in the message pan the message show that 1 row affected i want that instead of of this i will see the row which i have deleted.

Comment: I would leave in the code sample you just edited out.  It shows you've tried something which is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create trigger deltrig 
on client 
for delete 
as 
   select deleted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from [<YourTable>] output deleted.*
/* where ... */
```

Comment: Nice. Much simpler than a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

isnt something like this what you want?

```
create table #deleted(nr int)
create table #teste_d(nr int)
insert into #teste_d 
values(1),(2),(3)

delete from #teste_d
OUTPUT deleted.nr INTO #deleted
where nr = 2

select * from #deleted

drop table #deleted
drop table #teste_d
```

the resultset would be what was deleted

or if you really want to use trigger
should be instead delete or update

you should do something like

```
 insert into ##Data_deleted (col1,col2,...)
 select col1,col2,... from deleted
```